# Setting up MySQL circular replication in existing replication topology?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have the following MySQL replication topology set up for fault tolerance/disaster recovery with master server `A` and slaves `B` and `C`:

```
A replicates to B

A replicates to C
```

Both `B` and `C` are fully up to date with everything from `A` and have nothing in addition to that.  i.e. there is nothing in `B` and `C` that is not in `A`.

I would like to introduce circular replication such that:

```
A replicates to B
B replicates to A
```

A replicates to C

Changes made on `B` would replicate back to `A`. This would allow me to get more use out of a secondary server by spreading the load over two primary servers.

Primary use of each individual database on the servers would be limited to a specific server.  e.g. Users of database `bookingsystem` always access via server `B`, users of database `enquirysystem` always use server `A`. There is no danger of having to deal with changes to the same database in two different locations. The replication is purely for fault tolerance should there be a problem with either server.

Can I simply set server `A` to slave from server `B` and have this working straight away, or is there further preparatory, or subsequent work needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP01) Add this to /etc/my.cnf on ServerB

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

STEP02) Restart mysql on ServerB without replication running

```
service mysql restart --skip-slave-start
```

STEP03) On ServerB, run this in mysql client

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

You should see something like this:

```
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 | 590591464 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
```

STEP04) Record the Log File and Position from STEP03

STEP05) Restart mysql on ServerB as normal

```
service mysql restart
```

STEP06) Setup Replication User on ServerB

```
GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO ...
```

STEP07) On ServerA, run the following

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='IP Address of ServerB',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='replication username',
MASTER_PASSWORD='replication password',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='File From STEP04',
MASTER_LOG_POS=Position From STEP04;
```

Suppose ServerB's IP address is 10.1.2.30, replication user/pass is 'repluser'/'replpass'

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='10.1.2.30',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='repluser',
MASTER_PASSWORD='replpass',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=590591464;
```

STEP08) Start Replication on ServerA by running

```
START SLAVE;
```

STEP09) Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on ServerA

It should look something like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.89.147
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000109
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 636515875
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000038
                Relay_Log_Pos: 636509693
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000109
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 636515875
              Relay_Log_Space: 636509885
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If `Slave_IO_Running` and `Slave_SQL_Running` both say `Yes`, CONGRATULATIONS You've done it !!!

Give it a Try !!!