# MySQL my.cnf vs my-huge.cnf

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I've recently installed MySQL server and client 5.5.28 through rpm packages on an openSUSE machine, and I was not able to locate `my.cnf` file. I look into all directories `mysql --verbose --help | grep -C3 my.cnf` printed which was `/etc/my.cnf` (no such a file), `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`(no directory as `mysql`), `usr/etc/my.cnf` (don't have `etc` in my `usr`) and `~/.my.cnf` (doesn't exist). Then I tried `find / -name *.cnf` which gave me:

```
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-standard-5.0.24a/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-standard-5.0.24a/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-standard-5.0.24a/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-standard-5.0.24a/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-standard-5.0.24a/my-small.cnf 
/usr/share/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf
```

I want to edit `my.cnf` file to practice replication and high availability. I read somewhere that having `my.cnf` file won't be necessary to use MySQL well not in my case... so I was thinking to rename one these `my-*.cnf` to `my.cnf` and put it in the locations that MySQL would look for `my.cnf` file. But I'm not sure first if this would work, and second which one to pick to be able to practice replication.

I don't want to make it complex for myself, so I was thinking to take the medium one... Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing replication and you are just practicing, the `my.cnf` you choose is not that important. However, the smaller the config, the better. For example, if you DB Server has 2GB RAM, you should not choose `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf`.

If you started up mysql with a my.cnf, you create the default 10M or 18M `ibdata1` and 2 5M InnoDB log files (`ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`). The medium cnf has the following InnoDB settings:

```
[root@******** ~]# cat /usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf | grep innodb
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Since everything related to InnoDB is commented out, you should OK to choose `my-medium.cnf`

Simply run this:

```
cp /usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
service mysql restart
```

Now, as for MySQL Replication, I have Good News : I already answered a post back on `Feb 06, 2012` ( [How to setup replication(Master/slave) in MySQL 5.5.20?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/how-to-setup-replicationmaster-slave-in-mysql-5-5-20/12352#12352) ) with all the steps you need to automate a Slave's creation.

Here is a couple more of my posts with more advanced replication setups

- `May 07, 2012` : [Setting Circular Replication in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/setting-circular-replication-in-mysql/17532#17532)
- `Sep 24, 2012` : [Setting up MySQL circular replication in existing replication topology?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24798/setting-up-mysql-circular-replication-in-existing-replication-topology/24830#24830)
- `Nov 26, 2012` : [Replicate MySQL 5.0 Master to 5.5 Slave?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/replicate-mysql-5-0-master-to-5-5-slave/29324#29324)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. For the replication I'm setting up a master-master though. The process should share lots of steps with master-salve I think... Thanks anyway.