# Create a mysql slave database from master database

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have a mysql master database running. I want to have a slave database. So, I stopped the master mysql database and copied it to the slave machine. I had bin log enabled on master so even those files are copied.

I am not sure, how to start replication on the slave. Any help would be appreciated.

I am still copying data into slave.

```
mysql> show master status;
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mydbm1-bin.008524 |  1330529 |              |                  |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By the way, many new rows have been inserted into the master after the snapshot is copied to slave.

Comment: Please run this command on the Slave on the OS : `ls -l /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Please also run on the Master in mysql : `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`

Comment: I am still copying data into slave.

Comment: mysql> show master status;
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mydbm1-bin.008524 |  1330529 |              |                  |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 1):

Going by your question, I will like to review what I believe you did thus far:

- You stopped mysql on the Master
- You copied Master's /var/lib/mysql to the Slave's /var/lib/mysql
- I surmise the binlogs on the Master were copied as well

Look at the Slave's last binlog. From the question, it should be

- `mydbm1-bin.008524`
- Filesize 1330529

Believe it or not, you have to do a few things:

1) On the Master, create a replication user like this:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT
ON *.* TO replicator@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'r3plic4t0R';
```

2) Make /var/lib/mysql on the Slave owned by `mysql` user

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

3) Make sure Master's server_id is explicitly set in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
server_id = 1
```

4) Make sure Slave's server_id is explicitly set in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
server_id = 2
```

5) Startup mysql on the Slave

```
service mysql start
```

6) Setup replication by running this on the Slave

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='IPAddressOfMaster',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='replicator',
MASTER_PASSWORD='r3plic4t0R',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mydbm1-bin.008524',
MASTER_LOG_POS=1330529;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(5);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

You will see something like this:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: 10.48.20.253
                Master_User: replicant
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 60
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000254
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 858190247
             Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.066069
              Relay_Log_Pos: 873918
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000254
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB:
        Replicate_Ignore_DB:
         Replicate_Do_Table:
     Replicate_Ignore_Table:
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error:
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 858190247
            Relay_Log_Space: 873772
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File:
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File:
         Master_SSL_CA_Path:
            Master_SSL_Cert:
          Master_SSL_Cipher:
             Master_SSL_Key:
      Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If `Slave_IO_Running` and `Slave_SQL_Running` are both `Yes`, CONGRATULATIONS !!!

I already answered a post back on Feb 06, 2012 ( [How to setup replication(Master/slave) in MySQL 5.5.20?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/how-to-setup-replicationmaster-slave-in-mysql-5-5-20/12352#12352) ) with essentially the same steps.

I wanted to add additional posts I made for setting up Circular Replication should you decide to setup the two DB servers as Master/Master

- `Sep 24, 2012` : [Setting up MySQL circular replication in existing replication topology?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24798/setting-up-mysql-circular-replication-in-existing-replication-topology/24830#24830)
- `May 07, 2012` : [Setting Circular Replication in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/setting-circular-replication-in-mysql/17532#17532)